# <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> in "Fetch as Google"

Tags: google, google-search-console, noindex, fetch-as-google

I don't know why but when I execute "fetch as Google" it returns me

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDQACRADAQ=ECAINNFBMGNDEPAEBKBLOBOP; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 15:18:29 GMT
Content-Length: 153

<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

The `noindex` doesn't exist.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "The noindex doesn't exist"? Where doesn't it exist?

Answer (score 2):

Those are your page's HTTP headers, not your page's meta tag contents. That's why you don't see that tag's value there.

If you want that value sent with your headers then you cannot use HTML for this. You can accomplish it by using .htaccess, though:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
```